# Simple Linked List Pointer (and Error) Issues

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm a Noob, struggling with C, pointers and linked lists (well, everything really). I'm trying to build a very simple linked list of linked lists, but am getting error messages that 'member reference base type 'struct node*' is not a structure or a union. Having struggled for awhile, it dawns on me that next across your list of lists can both point to the next list item in both places, but am not sure whether I require 2 types of nodes, or what the better way to do this is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// node that can hold char * (strings) and next
struct node {
    char* data;
    struct node * next;
};

/*
I'm trying to create a linked list (containing List 1 and List 2) of linked lists, i.e.

    List 1         List 2
    1A               2A
    1B               2B

Where only nodes 1A, 1B, 2A and 2B have unique data (List 1 data just pointers to 1A data, List1 next just points to 1A next etc.)
*/

int main()
{

    // Will contain pointers to the heads of the 2 linked lists
    struct node** list_1 = NULL;
    struct node** list_2 = NULL;

    // Nodes under list_1
    struct node* one_a = NULL;
    struct node* one_b = NULL;

    // Nodes under linked list b
    struct node* two_a = NULL;
    struct node* two_b = NULL;

    // allocate 6 nodes in the heap
    list_1 = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    list_2 = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    // list 1 will contain
    one_a = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    one_b = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // list 2 will contain
    two_a = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    two_b = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // create linked list holding heads of 2 linked lists (i.e. first_list and second_list)

    // populate list1
    one_a->data = "a";
    one_a->next = one_b;
    one_b->data = "apple";
    one_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list2
    two_a>data = "be";
    two_a->next = two_b;
    two_b->data = "bite";
    two_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list of lists
    list_1->data = one_a->data;
    list_1->next = list_2;
    list_2->data = two_a->data;
    list_2->next = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Which one is the head of this list of lists?

Comment: `list_1` is not a pointer to `struct` but a pointer to a pointer, so the use of `->` is invalid in the last bunch of assignments.

Comment: Why don't you try something like 
```struct node {
    char* data;
    struct node * next;
    struct node *innerListHead;
};``` ? You make your life complicated with those double pointers.

Comment: @vasile_t but that's exactly what he did

Comment: @Jabberwocky as I can understand, the inner list is not a list but an array? Like here ```/*allocate 6 nodes in the heap*/ list_1 = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));``` But there is just a single node, not six. Do I get it wrong?

Comment: @vasile_t yes more or less. Actually he wants a linked list of lists but he's mixing it up with a pointer to pointer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list_1 and list_2 are being defined as pointers to pointers of the node.
What you really want is list_1 and list_2 to to be a node but their data to be pointers to other nodes. Since the node structure you defined has the data defined as a character pointer, your current node will not work for list_1 and list_2. You can change the structure to use a [void-pointer](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/void-pointers-in-c/) or you can create a new structure for holding nodes.
The easier solution would be to use a new structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// node that can hold char * (strings) and next
struct node {
    char* data;
    struct node * next;
};

// node that can hold lists of nodes and next
struct lnode {
    struct node* data;
    struct lnode * next;
};


/*
I'm trying to create a linked list (containing List 1 and List 2) of linked lists, i.e.

    List 1         List 2
    1A               2A
    1B               2B

Where only nodes 1A, 1B, 2A and 2B have unique data (List 1 data just pointers to 1A data, List1 next just points to 1A next etc.)
*/





int main()
{

    // Will contain pointers to the heads of the 2 linked lists
    struct lnode* list_1 = NULL;
    struct lnode* list_2 = NULL;

    // Nodes under list_1
    struct node* one_a = NULL;
    struct node* one_b = NULL;

    // Nodes under linked list b
    struct node* two_a = NULL;
    struct node* two_b = NULL;

    // allocate 6 nodes in the heap
    list_1 = malloc(sizeof *list_1); //This style of malloc is better in the C language
    list_2 = malloc(sizeof *list_2);

    // list 1 will contain
    one_a = malloc(sizeof *one_a);
    one_b = malloc(sizeof *one_b);

    // list 2 will contain
    two_a = malloc(sizeof *two_a);
    two_b = malloc(sizeof *two_b);
    // create linked list holding heads of 2 linked lists (i.e. first_list and second_list)

    // populate list1
    one_a->data = "a";
    one_a->next = one_b;
    one_b->data = "apple";
    one_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list2
    two_a->data = "be";
    two_a->next = two_b;
    two_b->data = "bite";
    two_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list of lists
    list_1->data = one_a;//one_a is a pointer to the list
    list_1->next = list_2;
    list_2->data = two_a; //two_a is a pointer to the list
    list_2->next = NULL;

}
```

Comment: The casts before malloc are not necessary in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Good point! I added them because they were part of his original code. I will remove this because it is not a good practice.

Comment: To take that one step further. The best practice for C would be to `list_1 = malloc(sizeof *list_1);`

Comment: Thanks Adam, code was simple enough for me to follow. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve what you are trying to do with only that structure. You need at least two pointers, one for the elements of the list of lists and the other for the list of `char*`.

The closest you can get here with the code you have is to an array of lists, using:

```
list_1 = (struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node*) *  SIZE);
```

In order to achieve what you want you need some sort of structures like the following:

```
struct node{
  char* data;
  node* next;
};

struct list{
   list* next;
   node* curr_list;
};
```

As you can see, now you have a special node for the list of list which points both to the next list of lists element as well as to a *normal* list of strings.

The following is the full example code with a `main`.
You can try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Eq2Eo0yDkdBOVwym).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// node that can hold char * (strings) and next
struct node{
  char* data;
 struct  node* next;
};

struct list{
   struct list* next;
   struct node* curr_list;
};


int main(){


    struct node node2;
    node2.data="second";
    node2.next=NULL;


    struct node node1;
    node1.data="first";
    node1.next=&node2;

    struct list l1;
    l1.next=NULL;
    l1.curr_list= &node1;

    struct node node4;
    node4.data="fourth";
    node4.next=NULL;

    struct node node3;
     node3.data="third";
    node3.next= &node4;

    struct list l2;
    l2.next=NULL;
    l2.curr_list= &node3;

    l1.next = &l2;

    struct list* pl = &l1;
    int i = 0;
    while(pl){
         printf("%s %d\n","list",i++);

        struct node* n = pl->curr_list;
        while(n){
            printf("%s\n",n->data);

            n=n->next;
        }
        pl = pl->next;   
       printf("\n");
    }


 return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Wrong language: the question is tagged C and your code in the answer is C++

Comment: The `cout` is just _one_ problem

Answer (score 0):

Using Adam's answer, (and the logic by Davide regarding the print function), I ended up with the following demonstration of a simply, singly linked list in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// node that can hold char * (strings) and next
struct node {
    char* data;
    struct node * next;
};

// node that can hold lists of lnodes and next
struct lnode {
    struct node* data;
    struct lnode * next;
};

/*
I'm trying to create a linked list (containing List 1 and List 2) of linked lists, i.e.

    List 1         List 2
    1A               2A
    1B               2B

Where only nodes 1A, 1B, 2A and 2B have unique data (List 1 data just pointers to 1A data, List1 next just points to 1A next etc.)
*/

int main()
{

    // Will contain pointers to the heads of the 2 linked lists
    struct lnode* list_1 = NULL;
    struct lnode* list_2 = NULL;

    // Nodes under list_1
    struct node* one_a = NULL;
    struct node* one_b = NULL;

    // Nodes under linked list b
    struct node* two_a = NULL;
    struct node* two_b = NULL;

    // allocate 6 nodes in the heap
    list_1 = malloc(sizeof *list_1); //This style of malloc is better in the C language
    list_2 = malloc(sizeof *list_2);

    // list 1 will contain
    one_a = malloc(sizeof *one_a);
    one_b = malloc(sizeof *one_b);

    // list 2 will contain
    two_a = malloc(sizeof *two_a);
    two_b = malloc(sizeof *two_b);

    // create linked list holding heads of 2 linked lists (i.e. first_list and second_list)
    // populate list1
    one_a->data = "a";
    one_a->next = one_b;
    one_b->data = "apple";
    one_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list2
    two_a->data = "be";
    two_a->next = two_b;
    two_b->data = "bite";
    two_b->next = NULL;

    // populate list of lists
    list_1->data = one_a;//one_a is a pointer to the list
    list_1->next = list_2;
    list_2->data = two_a; //two_a is a pointer to the list
    list_2->next = NULL;

    // to iterate over seperate lists (i.e. a's, b's, c's etc.)
    struct lnode *lists = list_1;
    while (lists){
        // to iterate through individual lists,(i.e. 'a', 'apple' etc.)
        struct node *head = lists->data;
        while (head) {
            printf("%s\n", head->data);
            head = head->next;
        }   
    lists = lists->next;
    } 

}
```